# SNMP Получить статус ошибок (hrPrinterDetectedErrorState) от принтера

Tags: принтер, snmp

Друзья, будьте добры помогите разобраться с возвращаемым принтером значением, запрошенным по snmp. Суть такова - имеется задача получать статус принтера Xerox и наличие/отсутствие у него ошибок по протоколу snmp. Со статусом принтера проблем никаких нет - я запрашиваю hrPrinterStatus (OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.5.1.1.1) и получаю понятное строковое значение (к примеру idle(3)), но вот с его ошибками какая то муть, дело в том что возвращаемое значения для запроса текущих ошибок hrPrinterDetectedErrorState (OID  .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.5.1.2.1) имеет тип "OCTET-STRING" и совсем не понятно каким образом извлечь из возвращаемого значения какую-то полезную для себя информацию.
Спецификация RFC 3805 для этого объекта говорит что:

> "This object represents any error conditions detected by the
>     printer.  The error conditions are encoded as an OCTET STRING
>      with the following definitions:
>
> ```
>     Condition          Bit #
>
>     lowPaper             0
>     noPaper              1
>     lowToner             2
>     noToner              3
>     doorOpen             4
>     jammed               5
>     offline              6
>     serviceRequested     7
>
>     inputTrayMissing     8
>     outputTrayMissing    9
>     markerSupplyMissing 10
>     outputNearFull      11
>     outputFull          12
>     inputTrayEmpty      13
>     overduePreventMaint 14
>
>     Bit # 15 is not assigned.
> ```
>
> Bits are numbered starting with the most significant bit of
>           the first byte being bit 0, the least significant bit of the
>           first byte being bit 7, the most significant bit of the
>           second byte being bit 8, and so on.  A one bit encodes that the 
>           condition was
>        detected, while a zero bit encodes that the condition
>        was not detected.

для того чтобы (если я правильно понял её перевод) мне что-либо полезное для себя подчерпнуть из hrPrinterDetectedErrorState, то мне нужно возвращенное значение octet-string представить как последовательность бит и в зависимости от того какой бит в получившейся последовательности равен 1 то и будет та ошибка из таблички выше. Ок, у меня есть два принтера Xerox - сделал запрос на оба

1 вернул 0x81 00

2 вернул 0x81 04

А вот дальше у меня начинаются затруднения. 0x81 04 это же шестнадцатеричный формат? Если так то дальше я его перевожу в двоичный и получаю вот такое значение

0000 0000 1000 0001 0000 0100

В нем бит больше чем 16 (сколько показано в таблице), как быть? Правильно ли я вообще перевел? Каким образом сопоставить получившееся значение с таблицей ошибок?

Comment: А первые восемь нулей - откуда? 1000 0001 0000 0100 - low paper, serviceRequested, inputTrayEmpty

Comment: @Outtruder Благодарю, вроде всё так и есть, поленился вручную перевести, видимо библиотека с помощью которой перевожу дописывает 1 байт в начало октета. Оформите коммент как ответ чтобы я мог закрыть этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первые восемь нулей - лишние? 1000 0001 0000 0100 - дают следующий набор флагов: low paper, serviceRequested, inputTrayEmpty.